# SQLDependency with DI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, sqldependency

I want to use SQLDependency along with Dependency Injection in my project. Here is my code

```
public interface IAreaRepository
{
   string GetAreaQuery();
   List<Area> GetAreas();
}

public class AreaRepository: IAreaRepository
{
    public AreaRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
       _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public string GetAreaQuery()
    {
       return _dbContext.Areas.ToString();
    }

    public string GetAreas()
    {
       return _dbContext.Areas.ToList();
    }
}
```

and Here is my class

```
public class AreaDataProvider
{
    private readonly AreaRepository _areaRepository;
    public AreaDataProvider(IAreaRepository areaRepository)
    {
       _areaRepository = areaRepository;
    }

    public void RegisterForNotification()
    {
        var connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
          var areaQuery = _areaRepository.GetAreaQuery(); // Line 1
          connection.Open();
          using (var oCommand = new SqlCommand(areaQuery, connection))
         {
            // Starting the listener infrastructure...
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            var oDependency = new SqlDependency(oCommand);
            oDependency.OnChange += OnNotificationChange;

            var reader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }  

    private void OnNotificationChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
       // Area Table has changed, Get the latest state from Db
       var areas = _areaRepository.GetAreas(); // Line 2
       RegisterForNotification();
    }
}
```

Now My issue is how to call initialise AreaDataProvider, because if I passed IAreaRepository with a DBContext like the one below.

```
using (AppContext context = new AppContext())
{
   AreaDataProvider provider = new AreaDataProvider(new AreaRepository(context));
   provider.RegisterForNotification();
}
```

My DbContext will be different in Line 1 and 2. What is the best way to achieve single DbContext across the AreaDataProvider class.

Comment: What's line 1 and 2? Anyways you could have a default constructor for the `AreaDataProvider` object that creates its own instance of DbContext and passes that to the repository.

Comment: Line 1 and 2 are commented in code above, Basically, they are two separate calls where repository (Db) is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

> DbContext will be different in Line 1 and 2.

No it won't.  It will be the same AreaRepository passed to the constructor.